# Replacing @ symbols in regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following text:

`Title %%% info@mydomain.com`

I have the following script:

```
update: function(){
    this.AjaxImage(this.mainImage.current);
    // /[$-/:-?{-~!"^_`\[\]]/ Updated 05.22.10, changed .replace(/%%%[^%]*/,' ') to .replace(/%%%.*/,' ') because an escaped space (%20) was causing markup to appear on the page. DE 
    // only show the title and year below the image, %%% is the delimiter
    var caption = this.detailBin[this.mainImage.current]
                      .innerHTML.replace(/%%%.*/,' '); 
    this.overlayCaption('hide');
    this.controls.counter.update(this.mainImage.current+1);
    this.utilities.updateHash(this.mainImage.current+1);
    this.captionUnderlay.update(caption);

    // show everything under "more info"
    this.captionText = this.detailBin[this.mainImage.current]
                           .innerHTML.replace('%%%',' '); 
    this.hasMoreInfo = (this.captionText.length > caption.length+9) ? true : false;
    if(!this.hasMoreInfo) 
        this.controls.captionToggle.hide();
    else 
        this.controls.captionToggle.show();
}

this.captionUnderlay.update(this.detailBin[this.currentImage]
                                .innerHTML.replace(/%%%[^@]*/," "));
```

The captionUnderlay above will show `@mydomain.com`.

I can solve the problem using the kludge below, but I want to understand what the problem is (I'm taking over the code that was written by someone else).

If I remove `[^@]` from the regular expression, it shows everything. If I substitute `[^@]` for `[^}]` it works fine unless I have a `}` in the text.

How do I prevent this from occurring?

Comment: `'Title %%% info@mydomain.com'.replace(/%%%.*/,' ')` --- why isn't it the expected result? (`Title` followed by 2 spaces, doesn't stop on `@`)

Comment: Is there a line break in it? `\n` or `\r`.

Comment: zerkms: I want Title to show, but instead Title @mydomain.com shows.

Comment: Sort of: no line break is in it.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the exact HTML containing the text.  I don't think their is a problem with your Regex, except that it probably doesn't match the HTML you have. See a working fiddle using your Regex at http://jsfiddle.net/P4mPs/ (uses jQuery to get the HTML).

Comment: @user2654985: I took your code and run it - the `Title` is shown. Check the first comment

Comment: tvanfosson: I've added more code and a temporary fix to my question. I just need to understand why it's working like this now. Thanks.

Comment: @zerkms First replace is indeed correct - he seems to actually be referring to the one at the bottom (`.replace(/%%%[^@]*/," ")`)

Answer (score 2):

```
.replace(/%%%[^@]*/," ")
```

Is looking for `%%%` followed by 0 or more characters that are not a `@`. Given the string `"Title %%% info@mydomain.com"` - that means it finds `%%% info` (as there is an @ symbol after info), which is then replaced by a space (`," "`). Making the string `"Title  @mydomain.com"`.

The expression at the top of the code is actually correct if you only want `"Title "`

```
.replace(/%%%.*/,' ')
```

As this finds any character (`.`) 0 or more times after 3 percent signs. This does however leave the space after `Title` - to correct this we would use the expression below for a fully trimmed return:

**Fixed expression**

```
.replace(/\s*%%%.*/,'')
```